# Finding the General Solution for a System of Differential Equations with Complex Eigenvalues

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I think I might just be having trouble with formatting my answer, because I'm fairly sure my work is right up until this point.

The question asks to find the general solution to $$X'= \begin{bmatrix}
        3 & 2 \\
        -1 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix} X$$

I found that the eigenvalues and eigenvectors are $$\lambda_1=2+i,v_1=\begin{bmatrix}
        -1-i \\
        1\\
        \end{bmatrix} \\
\lambda_1=2-i,v_1=\begin{bmatrix}
        -1+i \\
        1\\
        \end{bmatrix}. $$
According to the formula, I should be getting this as the general solution: 
$$x(t)=c_1e^{2t}\left(\begin{bmatrix}
        -1 \\
        1\\
        \end{bmatrix}\cos(t)-\begin{bmatrix}
        -1 \\
        0\\
        \end{bmatrix}\sin(t)\right)+c_2e^{2t}\left(\begin{bmatrix}
        -1 \\
        1\\
        \end{bmatrix}\sin(t)+\begin{bmatrix}
        1 \\
        0\\
        \end{bmatrix}\sin(t)\right) $$

What's confusing me is that Wolfram Alpha is giving me [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%27%3D%7B%7B3,2%7D,%7B-1,1%7D%7Dx), which looks like a different answer completely:

$$x(t)=\begin{bmatrix}
        2c_2e^{2t}\sin(t) + c_1e^{2t}(\sin(t)+\cos(t))\\
        c_2e^{2t}(\cos(t)-\sin(t))-c_1e^{2t}\sin(t) \\
        \end{bmatrix} $$

I understand that it's in a different format, but is it still equal to my answer above?

Comment: Your eigenvalues are $2$ and $2$. (Your matrix is lower triangular, so the eigenvalues are the entries on the main diagonal.)

Comment: Whoops. I sure did enter in the wrong matrix there. I somehow put in the matrix for another problem. I fixed it.

Comment: ... and in your formula for $x(t)$, that last $\sin(t)$ should be $\cos(t)$. ... But after some number crunching, you found an equivalent solution to WA's. (WA's $c_2$ is your $c_1$, and WA's $c_1$ is equal to your $-c_1-c_2$, more precisely.)

Comment: But after some number crunching, you found an equivalent formula to WA's. (WA's $c_2$ is your $c_1$, and WA's $c_1$ is equal to your $-c_1-c_2$, more precisely.)  If you had initial conditions, you'd get the same answer as WA.